# Site icons with alpha channel for self-hosted Wordpress blog network

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, images

Either I'm missing something (or have something badly configured in my self-hosted blog network) or when I'm uploading a transparent `.png` file (with alpha channel) using Media Library, my Wordpress installation makes all possible cropped versions *loosing transparency*.

This way, when I'm picking a perfectly transparent image for my site icon, I end up with favicons having ugly looking white background. To make things even worse, Wordpress' Media Library uses some weird size reduction algorithm, which causes my perfectly white / transparent background to be composite with all different shades of white / gray on all cropped images.

Is there any way to workaround this problem? Is this something in my configuration or is this another bug (loosing transparency / alpha channel when resizing image couldn't be a feature).

The only way I found to workaround this, is to download all cropped image files (after upload) through FTP, manually correct them (add transparency or fix background color) and re-upload them back, overwriting files generated by Wordpress. But, that sounds like a madness...

Comment: Does this only happens for site icons or do you see the same thing happening when you upload a transparent png file through the media library? It worked for me few days ago with such a file.

Comment: @birgire No. As I stated in the first line of my question: "(...) _when I'm uploading a transparent `.png` file (with alpha channel) **using Media Library**_ (...)" -- that means, that this happens always, no matter what destination for uploaded image is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be an issue with WordPress – but that should have been fixed 5 years ago:  [Preserve PNG transparency/alpha during thumbnail creation](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2805)

If you're using a newer WP installation (which I suppose) this issue might be rather a problem with the GD library of your server than with WordPress. And as far as I know this issues only occurs with 8bit pngs. Using 24bit pngs you should be on the safe side.

I found this 'suggestion' over at the [wordpress support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/transparent-pngs-issue). However I can not confirm this 'bug-fix' myself since my webserver seems to render both 8 bit and 24 bit images just fine ([tested here](http://www.cpu20.com/2015/wordpress-transparency-png-images/) with WP 4.3, GD bundled 2.1.0 compatible, PHP Version 5.3).

Comment: You have most certainly hit the point with that 8-bit `.png` file, which I was making somewhat automatically from 24-bit source files. Without conversion to 8-bit and with uploading 24-bit file through Media Library, everything seems fine about alpha channel and transparency. Thank you...